# Threaded HttpWebResponse doesn't always fire

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

This code is being run within a web service.  Sometimes it executes fine and sometimes it seems like the thread doesn't make the call out to the url.  I also never see the log events that are written inside the HttpWebResponse using statement.  I'm not sure what is going on, any help please?

```
HttpWebRequest urlRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
urlRequest.Method = "POST";
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JSON);
urlRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
urlRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            new Logger().Info("data length = " + data.Length.ToString());
                            new Logger().Info(JSON);
                            new Logger().Info("Before posting to ERPFullAppointmentCheckout controller");
                            using (Stream stream = urlRequest.GetRequestStream())
                            {
                                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                                new Logger().Info("Before using HttpWebResponse");
                                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)urlRequest.GetResponse())
                                {
                                    new Logger().Info("Inside using HttpWebResponse");
                                    string receivedresponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                                    string statuscode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                                    new Logger().Info("Response from POST: " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedresponse) ? "" : receivedresponse));
                                    new Logger().Info("Status Code: " + statuscode);
                                }
                            }


                            new Logger().Info("After posting to ERPFullAppointmentCheckout controller");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            new Logger().Error("Error posting to ERPFullAppointmentCheckout controller", ex);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: That code right there is the minimal.  Sometimes this is working and sometimes it is not.  I can't find any errors in the EventViewer, even from WAS.  There is nothing showing on the network that some of these calls are getting blocked.  There is nothing showing up in the Virus scanner saying that it blocked some calls.  Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The value of url is insignificant.  Like I said sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't.  This works in some environments all of the time.  There is one environment that I am troubleshooting that it doesn't seem to work all the time, but it works some of the time.  I can't duplicate that for you, but I can provide the code (above) and maybe there is something that I am not seeing.  I have since moved the declaration of "urlRequest" to inside the "ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem".  I am thinking that maybe that variable is sometimes disposed before the request is actually made.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem
```

Instead of:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
```

Look at these 2 links for more information on the difference...

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/